# React replace state array using hooks

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to replace a state array using a separately given array. I am unable to get my state to update to hold the values of the separate array. I've tried several things

```
   const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState([]);

    window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
        if (message.length > userFriendsList.length)
        {
            console.log(message)
            setUserFriendsList(message);
            console.log(userFriendsList)
        }
    });
```

```
    const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState({friendsList: []});

    window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
        if (message.length > userFriendsList['friendsList'].length)
        {
            console.log(message)
            setUserFriendsList({friendsList : message});
            console.log(userFriendsList)
        }
    });
```

```
const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState([]);

    window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
        if (message.length > userFriendsList.length)
        {
            console.log(message)
            setUserFriendsList([ ... userFriendsList, message]);
            console.log(userFriendsList)
        }
    });
```

None of these are updating the state.

Edit:
Component -

```
const FriendsList = () =>
{
    const [checkFriendsList, setCheckFriendsList] = useState(true)
    const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState([]);

    window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
        console.log(message)
        setUserFriendsList(oldFriendList => [ ...oldFriendList, ...message]);
        console.log(userFriendsList)
    });

    useEffect ( () => {
        if (checkFriendsList)
        {
            setCheckFriendsList(false);
            window.chatAPI.getFriendsList();
        }
    }, [checkFriendsList])

    return (
        <div className="friends-list-container">
            <List className="friends-list">
                <ListItem className="friends-list-title"> Friends List </ListItem>
            </List>
        </div>
    );
}
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the condition `if (message.length > userFriendsList.length)`.
If `message` is a non empty-string it will always be longer that your empty `userFriendsList` state, remove the condition and update the array with:

```
const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState([]);

window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
    setUserFriendsList(oldFriendList => [ ...oldFriendList, message]);
});
```

If `message` is an array just do:

```
const [userFriendsList, setUserFriendsList] = useState([]);

window.chatAPI.recvFriendsList(message => {
    setUserFriendsList(oldFriendList => [ ...oldFriendList, ...message]);
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it continues to not work :/

I'll update my post with the entire component and the output of the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the if statement.

```
// if( your condition)
{
   setUserFriendsList([ ... userFriendsList, ...message]);
}
```

Comment: This did not work, I updated my post to show the full component and output.

Comment: Your second console.log is called immediately after the call to setUserFriendList -- but the value of userFriendList won't be updated until the next render, so what is being logged is not actually the new value of userFriendList but the old one. If you move that console.log into the main function you might see the values you're looking for.